# X3D files won't load with a URL

Tags: java, x3d

I'm making a Xj3D Test class in Java and it's meant to display `X3D` and `X3DV` files. It does work with some test files. But when it comes to the `X3D` files that I've been given, they don't get displayed and I get an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.web3d.x3d.sai.InvalidURLException: Unable to load any URLS
    at org.web3d.vrml.scripting.external.sai.SAIBrowser.createX3DFromURL(SAIBrowser.java:846)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.<init>(Xj3DTest.java:50)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.main(Xj3DTest.java:56)
```

I've done some research and I've seen that I might need to use the `createX3DFromStream` method instead of the `createX3DFromURL` method that I currently have in my Java code. I realise that it's the URL within the `X3D` and `X3DV` files that's causeing the problem and I need to get rid of the error as it's prohibiting me from continuing the project. The line in my `Java` code that's causing the problem is: `X3DScene scene = browser.createX3DFromURL(new String[]   {"hafodty_cirlce_1.x3dv"});`. I have the `X3DV` file `hafodty_circle.x3dv` saved within my NetbeansProject folder for the project.

**EDIT**

The way that I got the `Browser` element was by the following line.

`Browser browser = x3dComponent.getBrowser();`

Comment: can you show how you got the "browser" object? You are supposed to get it like: X3DComponent component= BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(null); ExternalBrowser browser= component.getBrowser();. You also need to make sure that hafodty_cirlce_1.x3dv is valid and accessible.

Comment: @CpS I'll edit the question so it shows how I get the `browser` object. The file entitles `hafodty_circle_1.x3dv` is in the project folder and I know that `X3D` and `X3DV` files that are in the project can get loaded as I've tested my `Java` class with a simple red X3D cube.

Comment: if you can load a simple file (e.g. a cube) it means that there's a problem in the hafodty_circle_1.x3dv

Comment: @CpS When I've looked into the hafodty_circle_1.x3dv file, I saw that it has a view point tag and an imageTexture url tag which are causing the problems. But I don't know a way to get it fixed as when I take those out, there is no texture and the image is zoomed far too into the image.